# Reading distance xml node (distance) - Google Maps api - Delphi 6

Tags: xml, delphi, google-maps-api-3

I use the following code in Excel to return the distance between two points (Origin and Destination).

There is a similiar way to do this in Delphi 6?

I found several examples on the internet, but all use functions that do not exist in Delphi 6, perhaps because it is very old. For example, IHTMLDocument2 that Delphi 6 does not recognize.

```
  Function Km_Distance(Origin As String, Destination As String) As Double       
    Dim myRequest As XMLHTTP
    Dim myDomDoc As DOMDocument
    Dim distanceNode As IXMLDOMNode

    Let Km_Distance = 0

    On Error GoTo exitRoute

    Let Origin = Replace(Origin, " ", "%20")
    Let Destination = Replace(Destination, " ", "%20")        

    Set myRequest = New XMLHTTP

    myRequest.Open "GET", "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=" _
        & Origin & "&destination=" & Destination & "&sensor=false", False
    myRequest.send

    Set myDomDoc = New DOMDocument

    myDomDoc.LoadXML myRequest.responseText

    Set distanceNode = myDomDoc.SelectSingleNode("//leg/distance/value")
    If Not distanceNode Is Nothing Then Km_Distance = distanceNode.Text / 1000

exitRoute:
    Set distanceNode = Nothing
    Set myDomDoc = Nothing
    Set myRequest = Nothing
End Function
```

I can read the xml returned by the API (code below).

The question now is: how to read the distance in this xml on Delphi?
The equivalent of:
Set distanceNode = myDomDoc.SelectSingleNode("//leg/distance/value")

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  vXMLDoc: TXMLDocument;
  NodeRec: IXMLNode;
  aasdlkj : IXMLDocument;
  XMLFile: String;
begin

 XMLFile:= 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=Curitiba&destination=Joinville';
 vXMLDoc := TXMLDocument.Create(self);
 vXMLDoc.LoadFromFile(XMLFile); //Le Arquivo xml selecionado

 Memo1.Clear;
 Memo1.Lines.Add(vXMLDoc.XML.Text);

 How to do this?
 //NodeRec= vXMLDoc.SelectSingleNode("//leg/distance/value")

 if not vXMLDoc.Active Then
 exit;
 end;
```

Comment: " IHTMLDocument2 .. Delphi 6 does not recognize"  It will, if you set your project up correctly.  IHTMLDocument2 is one of a number of interfaces defined in the unit MSHTML.Pas that comes with Delphi (I don't have D6 but it definitely came with D5).  You need to add MSHTML to the Uses list of your Delphi code (and maybe add the path to it to your project settings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
Uses ... MSXML, UrlMon, ...

function TForm1.GetURL : String;
var
  Origin,
  Destination,
  URL : String;
begin
  Origin := StringReplace(edOrigin.Text, ' ', '#20', [rfReplaceAll]);
  Destination := StringReplace(edDestination.Text, ' ', '#20', [rfReplaceAll]);
  Result :=  GoogleMapsURL + '&origin=' + Origin + '&destination=' + Destination
    + '&sensor=false';
end;

procedure TForm1.GetXML;
var
  XMLDoc: IXMLDOMDocument;
  Node : IXMLDomNode;
  XMLUrl : String;
  XMLFileName: String;
begin

 XMLUrl := GetUrl;

 XMLFileName := 'C:\temp\temp.xml';

 URLDownloadToFile(Nil, PChar(XMLUrl), PChar(XMLFileName), 0, Nil);

 Memo1.Lines.LoadFromFile(XMLFileName);

 XMLDoc := CoDOMDocument.Create;
 XMLDoc.LoadXML(Memo1.Lines.Text);
 Node := XMLDoc.SelectSingleNode('//leg/distance/value');

 Memo1.Lines.Add(Node.Text);
end;
```

I've used `URLDownloadToFile` to download the XML because for some reason `XMLDoc.Load(GetURL)` returns an empty XML document.  I also tried loading the URL into a `TWebBrowser`, but my attempt to retrieve an IHtmlDocument2 interface from it also failed.  Whether these problems are specific to the googlemaps URL, I don't know - usually they (XMLDoc.Load and the IHtlmDocument2 interface of the TWebBrowser) both work fine.

**Update:**   It seems that the difficulty I was having using `XMLDoc.Load` to get the XML from the googlemaps url was because the import unit MSXML I was using is out of date.  The following works on Windows10 64-bit and avoids the need to use `URLDownloadToFile` (though actually I prefer to use that, because then I have the XML right in front of me).

```
procedure TForm1.GetXML2;
var
  XMLDoc: IXMLDOMDocument;
  Node : IXMLDomNode;
  XMLUrl : String;
  XMLFileName: String;
begin
 XMLDoc := CreateOleObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0') as IXMLDOMDocument;
 XMLDoc.async := False;

 XMLUrl := GetUrl;
 if not XMLDoc.load(XMLUrl) then
   exit;

 Assert(XMLDoc.DocumentElement <> nil);

 Node := XMLDoc.SelectSingleNode('//leg/distance/value');

 Memo1.Lines.Add(Node.Text);

end;
```

Comment: On my Delphi 6, shows: Undeclared identifier: 'IXMLDOMDocument'
Undeclared identifier: 'IXMLDomNode' 
Is necessary add more references on "uses"?

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked well. I just need to make some adjustments to my case, but that's what I needed.